# Fade in/out sound playing in 2 different Divs

Tags: javascript, jquery

JQuery has nice visual fadeIn/fadeOut functions that work on different elements such as `div`.  I need the same thing for sound.

More precisely, if two YouTube iFrame API players are playing from within 2 different `div`, is there a way to fadeIn/fadeOut the sound between them?

Answer (score 6):

Try something like this,

```
$('<div/>').animate({ left: 100 }, {
     duration: 1000,
     step: function(now, fx){
    var volume = now;
        player.setVolume(volume)
     }
   });
```

the `step` function will give you a callback on every change of the val and you can call the youtube player to set the volume.

I am not sure how fast the youtube player can respond to the volume set... but this method allows you to have jquery `tween` effects just like in a `div`

---

Example usage with `fadeTo` function,

```
$('<div/>').fadeTo({
     duration: 1000,
     step: function(now, fx){
        var volume = now * 100;
        player.setVolume(volume)
     }
},1);
```

Comment: Jim, I got .animate moving the div and changing the YouTube player volume.  However, setting opacity: 0.5 does not work and neither does .fadeTo. But, I have found jQuery examples with text.  What is different here is that YT video is in the div and maybe it can not be faded out?  Maybe I have a problem in my fiddle here ... http://jsfiddle.net/tesla/FE5wF/86/ ... Thanks everyone.

Comment: add >>>wmode: "opaque"<<< to your "playerVars"

Comment: Thanks Jim, actually I found wmode="transparent". Does it make difference?  However, my bigger question now is how to get $().animate and .fadeTo to run concurrently.  Actually, I do not need to .animate becase it does not handle opacity on all browsers, while .fadeTo does.  So I need some looping mechanism with callbacks during duration as .fadeTo has an ending callback only. What I am working towards is a youtube player with video (in/out) and audio (cross) fading between multiple videos/subsegments (hence 2 players because of buffering). Is there a better approach?  Thanks again.

Comment: womode="opaque" or "transparent" should work fine. Updated the answer with a "fadeTo" example

Comment: Maybe a better question for me to ask is whether there is any way to get a single yt iframe player to bugger ahead all or parts of next video while playing the current one?  Surprisingly, when i try using one player strictly for playing and another for buffering they seem not to be aware of and are not using what the other one has already buffered.  So, any alternatives or ideas?

Comment: you should post it as a new question :)

Answer (score 0):

This technique is called a cross-fade. If the YouTube API gives you access to the volume control (I haven't ever used the YouTube API players) it should be relatively easy to do at least a linear cross-fade (ie. not on a curve). However, jQuery does not in and of itself provide an additional abstraction layer for controlling any specific media players (or audio APIs in general).

Comment: Being a Web 0.2 Fellow ;) how would I best implement the loop (guessing with setInterval) so that it's looping at an optimal rate that would one one side not hog the cpu and on the other would not make the volume changes sound too choppy?

Comment: Beats me. ;-) I saw a yes/no question and stuck my nose in. Jim Jose has a pretty nifty idea, using a div as a "dummy" target in order to invoke the step parameter of the animate function.

Comment: @user556634 the embedded player does not offer volume control. You're going to want to accept a "no" as the answer to this question, as judging by your question and comment, doing this one is far far more difficult than you can imagine.  http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/player_parameters.html http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/player_parameters.html

Comment: @Sinetheta I think the embed player offers setVolume... see this http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/js_api_reference.html